# Magento how to use closed AND & OR condition with collection

Tags: magento

```
     select * from quote where created < '2020-05-12' and (((is_offer = 0 OR (is_offer is null and is_active = 1)) and
        (cart_status is NULL)) OR cart_status = 3) and status='completed';
```

How to write this query with magento collection model.
have tried but didn't get idea for this `(((is_offer = 0 OR (is_offer is null and is_active = 1)) and
            (cart_status is NULL)) OR cart_status = 3)`

Thanks in advance.